# Bootstrap confirmation won´t work

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Inside my main-page (bootstrap-confirmation script included below) there are some Tabs where the content is loaded by `ajax GET` method.

```
<div class="portlet-body">
   <div class="tab-content" id="tab_content">

       <div class="tab-pane active" 
         id="tab_open"
         data-refreshurl="noticelist.php?status=0"></div>
       <div class="tab-pane" 
           id="tab_done"
           data-refreshurl="noticelist.php?status=1"></div>
       <div  class="tab-pane" 
             id="tab_canceled"
             data-refreshurl="noticelist.php?status=2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for loading Tabs content:

```
$("#tab_open").load("noticelist.php?status=0", function (result) {
  App.blockUI({target: "#tab_content",animate: true});
  $("#tab_open").tab("show");
  App.unblockUI("#tab_content");
});
$(\'[data-toggle="tabajax"]\').click(function(e) {
    App.blockUI({target: "#tab_content",animate: true});
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr("href"),
        targ = $this.attr("data-target");
    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });
    $this.tab("show");
    App.unblockUI("#tab_content");
    return false;
});
```

Inside each Tab there is this link with a bootstrap-confirmation:

```
<a class="btn btn-icon-only red-mint deleteit" id="delete_'.$val['DS'].'"
                      data-toggle="confirmation" 
                      data-popout="true" 
                      data-btn-ok-label="'.T::ACTIONS_3.'"
                      data-btn-cancel-label="'.T::ACTIONS_4.'"
                      data-original-title="" 
                      data-on-confirm="shortwork"
                      data-job-id="del"
                      data-id="'.$val['DS'].'"
                      title="'.T::SYSMSG_0.'"
                      href="#"
                      ><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

When I click at the button nothing happens and the error-console is empty. I'm unsure what is wrong?

If I add the button directly into the main page, the confirmation will show correctly, why doesn't it work inside the ajax loading content method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code to the php-file wich given the content solved that problem.

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({ btnOkClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success', btnCancelClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'});
```